# Почему не работают сессии в yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

В контроллере:

```
Yii::$app->session->open();
$c = count($_SESSION['basket']);
$_SESSION['basket'][$c] = [];
$_SESSION['basket'][$c]['artikl'] = $material->artikl;
$_SESSION['basket'][$c]['photo'] = $material->photo;
$_SESSION['basket'][$c]['size'] = $size;
$_SESSION['basket'][$c]['color'] = $color;
```

Во вьюхе:

```
Yii::$app->session->open();
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Возвращается пустота. Почему так?

Comment: и зачем вы  еще раз стартуете сессию во вьюхе?

Comment: Открывать/закрывать сессию вручную не нужно: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-sessions-cookies#access-session-data